# iOS 7:UIWebView (Safari) crashes due to memory overflow

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, safari, crash, ios7

When I try to create big JSON object in iOS7 Safari (e.g. http://yadi.sk/d/yA4hY1OEBPpLZ) it crashes due to memory leak. But in iOS6 and in iOS7 simulator it works.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Can you give an example? How big is big?

Comment: open file attached here [link](http://yadi.sk/d/yA4hY1OEBPpLZ).
I don't know how to measure the precise value of the js memory size. In this example the object gradually increases by small portions. In the log on the ipad I see about 350 objects. After that the browser crashes.
In the emulator ios7 Profiler shows the amount of memory within 10 Mb, in ios7 device 300MB

Answer (score 0):

When you load 2MB or more of HTML, the UIWebView has to consume a lot of memory to create a DOM and all of the controls to actually show the page. The limit is not the HTML size, but the resulting amount of memory that is needed to display it. Run it in the simulator with the Activity Monitor to see memory consumption.

You'll need to break down your pages or find another way to do the markup to make the memory smaller. Note that just making the HTML smaller might not help if you need to create the same page.